# Grepping `reg query` result value?

Tags: scripting, batch-file, dos

Consider the following result from a hypothetical `reg query`:

```
..>reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\MediaPlayer /v "I
nstallation Directory"

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\MediaPlayer
    Installation Directory    REG_EXPAND_SZ    %ProgramFiles%\Windows Media Play
er
```

How do I grep the output so that I can assign the actual value of the setting (`%ProgramFiles%\...`) into a variable (or temp file)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

example for batch files:

```
@FOR /F "tokens=2* " %%A IN ('reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\MediaPlayer /v "Installation Directory"') DO @SET PARAM=%%B
```

If you want to use it directly in console - use single percent sign to denote variables (i.e. `%A` and `%B`)