# using piped commands with for /f on windows (with reg query)

Tags: windows, batch-file, registry

I am trying to query the install location of a program in the registry. All I'm interested in is the location output.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073486/grepping-reg-query-result-value) has a partial solution, but it doesn't quite help.
On Windows 7, the reg command outputs a stupid registry key header along with the value, as shown below:

```
reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\NSIS Unicode" /v InstallLocation

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\NSIS Unicode
InstallLocation    REG_EXPAND_SZ    C:\Program Files\NSIS
```

First, is there a way to turn off the header and simplify the output?

At the command prompt, I can change the above to

```
reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\NSIS Unicode" /v InstallLocation | findstr InstallLocation
```

so that it returns me just the second line.

Now, if I am to use a `FOR /F` to parse this and get only the directory value, the `FOR` command fails saying `| was unexpected at this time`.

Here's my batch file:

```
@for /f "tokens=2* delims=   " %%k in ('reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\NSIS Unicode" /v InstallLocation | findstr InstallLocation') do @echo %%k
```

So where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must escape the `|` character using a caret (`^`).

```
@echo off
setlocal

set KEY=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\NSIS Unicode
set V=InstallLocation

for /f "tokens=2* delims= " %%k in ('reg query "%KEY%" /v %V% ^| findstr "%V%"') do echo %%k
```

this would return `REG_SZ` on my machine.

Answer (score 3):

The pipe char is special and has to be escaped with `^`.

```
@for /f "tokens=2* delims=   " %%k in ('reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\NSIS Unicode" /v InstallLocation ^| findstr InstallLocation') do @echo %%k
```